# Calling Function in Function without Arguments

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Quick question:

I want to call a main function without any arguments, and within the main function, I have several other functions that do have arguments. How would I go about doing this?

Here are the multiple functions:

```
 # Takes the Portfolio dictionay, unpacks the multiple tuples, and calculates
 # the total price of the shares at time of purchase

def total_purchase_price(portfolio):
    totalprice = 0
    totalpurprice = 0
    for item in portfolio:
        purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = item
        totalprice += purprice * numshares
        totalpurprice = totalprice
    return totalpurprice

# Takes the Portfolio dictionay, unpacks the multiple tuples, and calculates
# the current total value of the shares

def total_value(portfolio):
    totalprice = 0
    totalvalueprice = 0
    for item in portfolio:
        purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = item
        totalprice += curprice * numshares
        totalvalueprice = totalprice
    return totalvalueprice   

# Takes the previous two functions, and subtracts them to get the total
# gain/lost of the shares

def total_gain(total_purchase_price, total_value, portfolio):
    gainlost = total_value - total_purchase_price
    return gainlost
```

ex. What I have right now (note: I know this won't work, just there for what I want, as each function returns a value):

```
def testQ1(total_purchase_price, total_value, total_gain, portfolio):
    print("Total Cost =", total_purchase_price)
    print("Current Value =", total_value)
    print("Total gain/lost =", total_gain)
    return
```

ex. What I want to achieve:

```
def testQ2():
    total_purchase_price(portfolio)
    total_value(portfolio)
    total_gain(total_purchase_price, total_value, portfolio)
    print("Total Cost =", total_purchase_price)
    print("Current Value =", total_value)
    print("Total gain/lost =", total_gain)
    return
```

How would I do this? Thanks

Comment: Are these values global and where are they initialized. Would `testQ2()` read them from a file and have another function that returns them?

Comment: You don't assign the return values to variables.

Comment: testQ2 needs to know what portfolio is, as sabbahillel says, you should use global vars OR make a class and then they can be an attribute to the class

Comment: I explain how to set up the variables in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Using a class might be easier:

```
class PortfolioParser:
    def __init__(self, portfolio):
        self.portfolio = portfolio
        self.price = self.total_purchase_price()
        self.value = self.total_value()
        self.gain = self.total_gain()

    def total_purchase_price(self):
        # Takes the Portfolio dictionay, unpacks the multiple tuples, and calculates
        # the total price of the shares at time of purchase
        totalprice = 0
        totalpurprice = 0
        for item in self.portfolio:
            purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = item
            totalprice += purprice * numshares
            totalpurprice = totalprice
        return totalpurprice      

    def total_value(self):
        # Takes the Portfolio dictionay, unpacks the multiple tuples, and calculates
        # the current total value of the shares
        totalprice = 0
        totalvalueprice = 0
        for item in self.portfolio:
            purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = item
            totalprice += curprice * numshares
            totalvalueprice = totalprice
        return totalvalueprice   

    def total_gain(self):
        # Takes the previous two functions, and subtracts them to get the total
        # gain/lost of the shares
        return self.value- self.price

    def testQ2(self):
        print("Total Cost = {0}\nCurrent Value = {1}\nTotal Gains = {2}".format(self.price, self.value, self.gain))
```

And then you would use it like so:

```
myPortfolio = # The portfolio to parse
parser = PortfolioParser(myPortfolio)
parser.testQ2()
```

Answer (score 1):

portfolio is the only argument that is not calculated within testQ2. You need to have a global value for it, or read it in (maybe in another function). After they have been calculated return the values in an appropriate order.

```
def testQ2():
    portfolio = getPortfolio()
    tp = total_purchase_price(portfolio)
    tv = total_value(portfolio)
    tg = total_gain(tp, tv, portfolio)
    print("Total Cost =", tp)
    print("Current Value =", tv)
    print("Total gain/lost =", tg)
    return portfolio, tp, tv, tg
```